# Trouble executing "bundle update"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows, aptana, bundle

I am learning RoR using Aptana. I created my first project and tried to update its Gemfile. It uses "sqlite3" by default. i wanted to configure it with mysql. i did configure it. but whenever i call `bundle update` to save the changes, it gives me following error:

```
sh: /c/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/bin/bundle: C:/Projects/railsinstaller/stage/Ruby1.9.2/bin/ruby.exe: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

Any Suggestions to get rid of this error??

Answer (score 0):

At first try

```
bundle install
```

not bundle update

Which mysql gem are you using? Have you installed ruby properly?